# Audio card driver problems Debian 11 (Creative Sound Blaster Recon3Di)

Tags: debian, audio, pop-os

I recently installed Pop!_OS alongside Windows 10 as I plan to get away from windows completely in the long run (except maybe in virtual machines).
Honestly though, I'd rather use Debian as Pop!_OS is too overloaded for me and everything I need, apart from that one thing, I can get running on Debian (I'm aware that Pop!_OS is based on Ubuntu and Ubuntu is based on Debian).

In Pop!_OS the audio card drivers run directly without me having to configure anything, however on Debian the audio card works but not everything is recognized as in Pop!_OS.

I have already downloaded the ALSA firmware, configured it (./configure) and built it (make) and moved the ctefx-r3di.bin for my audio card (Creative Sound Blaster Recon3Di) to the /usr/lib/firmware folder. However, everything is still unchanged, the audio card works on some ports but not all are recognized.

I have also tried for fun to copy all firmware files from Pop!_OS and paste them into Debian, but without success.

Is there a way where I can see exactly how Pop!_OS addresses the audio card with the drivers to transfer them to Debian ?

I have been using Debian for a long time but never had to do anything like this.

From another forum I was told to attach the output from the inxi command, which I am attaching here as well.
What I also noticed is that in AlsaMixer the audio card is specified as "HDA Intel PCH", but under Chip it says "Creative Recon3Di".

```
root@onepc:~# inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel C610/X99 series HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-4: Logitech G330 Headset type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.0.12-76060006-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.63 running: yes
  
  
root@onepc:~# inxi -b
System:
  Host: onepc Kernel: 6.0.12-76060006-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/1
    Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: X99-Gaming 5P v: x.x serial: N/A
    UEFI-[Legacy]: American Megatrends v: F20 date: 01/11/2016
CPU:
  Info: 6-core Intel Core i7-6800K [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 1733 min/max: 1200/3700
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia,nvidia tty: 190x49
  Message: GL data unavailable in console for root.
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet driver: alx
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 8.38 TiB used: 2.01 TiB (23.9%)
Info:
  Processes: 395 Uptime: 5h 38m Memory: 31.18 GiB used: 6.88 GiB (22.1%) Init: systemd
  runlevel: 5 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Thanks to the help in the Debian forum I was able to solve the problem: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=766484